# How to convert a char* into const char* in C

Tags: c, windows, pointers, constants, codeblocks

Is there any way to convert a char* into a const char* in the C language?
I use CodeBlocks as my IDE for Windows.
I heard that it isn't possible to do this in basic C. Is that true?

Comment: The conversion will happen automatically (if you try to assign `char *` to `const char *`), but you can use a cast if you want to.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat cast?

Comment: @kaylum In my programm, I have a const char* type of variable declared. Then, I change it to a char* type using strdup(). And now I need to turn it back to be a const char* type. I can't use another variable.

Comment: What do you mean "change it to a char * type"? Please show some code. It's probable you have some basic misunderstanding but without the actual code it is difficult to explain exactly what that misunderstanding is.

Comment: `strdup()` doesn't change the type of your variable, it just creates a new string which is a copy of the original (constant) one.

Answer (score 0):

> it isn't possible to do this in basic C

Based on your question alone, without any example code, the answer is no. You can assign a `char*` to a `const char*`. Consider the example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char * str;

    str = "abcdefg";

    const char * cstr = str;

    puts(cstr);

    return 0;
}
```

This is perfectly legal. If you are concerned about the compiler complaining you can do the following:

```c
const char * cstr = (const char*)str
```

This will explicitly convert the `char*` type to a `const char*` type. In the event that you want to pass it to a function `void f(const char* s)` you would do the following:

```c
f((const char*)str);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What exactly (const char*)str does? Where should I put it? And in my code I can't change the variable. Is there any way to convert the exact same pointer to a const pointer in C?

Comment: @KazzioBots I edited the second snippet so you can get a better idea of where to put it. You don't have to change the variable you just need to use a cast to indicate the const qualifier.